# How to get The Most Recent Record In A Table By Date

Tags: sql, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

```
    ID       eff_date                   term_date
-----------------------------------------------------
1   100     2013-01-01    0
2   100     2013-11-27    2017-12-31
3   101     2014-01-01    2018-12-31 
4   101     2013-11-27    2013-12-31
```

So Here there are two scenarios. one is to put the most recent record based on term_date and also in the 1st and two rows,same id but 2nd row is terminated but the 1st row is not. In that scenario I want to pull not terminated row. I know on how to the pull the most recent records based on dates but I am not sure on how to pull the record with zero.
Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: what data type is term_date that it allows both dates and a zero?

Comment: I dont understand your logic. Please use proper grammar and separate each sentence. Also show us what result you expect and why

Comment: You can add filter 'Where term_date is NULL' to get records that are not terminated.

Comment: @Aurelian 0 is not `NULL`

Comment: @Ctznkane525 This is a number data type.

Comment: the term date i meant

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Term_date is a number data type.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is how I understood the question (which is, in my opinion, as clear as mud).

First of all, storing (obvious) date values into VARCHAR2 columns is a bad idea. Putting a zero into it (instead of apparent absence of value) is also wrong.

Anyway, that's what you have. When comparing any value (which represents date) with a zero, it'll always be larger than 0 so you can freely take it. The only good point is that those "dates" are stored in yyyy-mm-dd format, which sorting makes simpler.

So, here it is:

```
SQL> with test (id, eff_date, term_date) as
  2    (select 100, '2013-01-01', '0'          from dual union
  3     select 100, '2013-11-27', '2017-12-31' from dual union
  4     select 101, '2014-01-01', '2018-12-31' from dual union
  5     select 101, '2013-11-27', '2013-12-31' from dual
  6    ),
  7  inter as
  8    (select id, eff_date, term_date,
  9       rank() over (partition by id order by term_date desc) rnk
 10     from test
 11    )
 12  select id, eff_date, term_date
 13  from inter
 14  where rnk = 1;

        ID EFF_DATE   TERM_DATE
---------- ---------- ----------
       100 2013-11-27 2017-12-31
       101 2014-01-01 2018-12-31

SQL>
```

Comment: he says above term date is a number...not sure how considering it has those dashes in it (at least thats how its being displayed)...just a comment though...i think this is right